# WPF Raise DoubleClick Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class derived from `WindowsFormsHost` that listens to WinForms mouse events. It works fine for single clicks but is there any way to trigger double client events? `ClickCount` is read-only so I can't set it, and raising `Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent` doesn't propagate it. Any other idea?

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) {
    MouseButton? wpfButton = ConvertToWpf(e.Button);
    if (!wpfButton.HasValue)
        return;

    RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, wpfButton.Value) {
        RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseDownEvent,
        Source = this
        //ClickCount = 2  // read-only
    });

    //RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs() {  // won't propagate
    //  RoutedEvent = System.Windows.Controls.Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent,
    //  Source = this
    //});
}
```

Comment: If you want to have Double and Single Click detection, that is a issue. You have to either: a) Delay the SingleClick event until you are certain it is not a double one. Wich can be set as high as a second in Windows. b) Undo the olast single click Handler as first action in the Double one.

Comment: Honestly if you try to raise a speicfic Click event, you are propably on the wrong track to begin with. You should be raising the function that double click calls. *Not* try to simulate a double click.

Answer (score 2):

Here is you would raise a `MouseDoubleClickEvent` programmatically in WPF:

```
MouseButtonEventArgs doubleClickEvent = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks, MouseButton.Left);
doubleClickEvent.RoutedEvent = Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent;
doubleClickEvent.Source = this;
RaiseEvent(doubleClickEvent);
```

Comment: I tried again. RaiseEvent gets called, but MouseDoubleClickEvent doesn't get triggered.

Comment: It certainly does for me so then you are doing something wrong. Maybe you should consider providing a MCVE of your issue instead of downvoting answers that actuallt answers the question you are asking?